# Better arraylist performance option to reset object

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

In Java arrayList I have two different list for same class `TGrid`. one have approx 1000 and other have 10 elements.
Now in my functionality I have to reset some of element as per if/else condition
Here I have two option to perform same thing **BUT** I need to know which will be better for performance.

**Class:**

```
public class TGrid{

    private String pType;
    private boolean one ;
    private boolean one6;
    private boolean one7;
    private boolean three2;

    getter --- setter
}
```

Now in functionality, To reset object

Option 1:

```
tGridList.get(count).setPType("");
tGridList.get(count).setOne(false);
tGridList.get(count).setOne6(false);
tGridList.get(count).setOne7(false);
tGridList.get(count).setThree2(false);
```

Option 2:

```
tGridList.set(count, new TGrid());
```

**Question:** Which option will give better performance?

Comment: The options are not compatible  as given. Maybe you should rewrite the first line in option1 to tGridList.get(count).setPType(null);

Comment: I don't have to clear all list. Just have to reset some of them as require

Comment: @cybye it's ok. It may be not more important for me NOW

Answer (score 1):

I **assume** that first option is faster. In both options you have setting the values. In the first option it is done explicitly, and in the second option it is done implicitly by the constructor after the object is created. So the main difference between first and second option is the constructor call for the second option. So this extra work, I think, will cause weaker performance for the second option.

But, you have to do some performance testing in order to get confident results.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the first option is the faster over time. you should rewrite it as

```
TGrid t = tGridList.get(count);
t.setPType("");
t.setOne(false);
t.setOne6(false);
t.setOne7(false);
t.setThree2(false);
```

or even introduce a clear()-Method in TGrid.

Compared to the second option this will not run into blocking-issues. The new-call in the second can stop the whole VM under memory stress.

The bad-side of this is that you change the instance, means you have to care for synchronization. Where "to care" includes actively ignoring it ;)